# Real world examples of DAAST (IAB Standard-Digital Audio Ad Serving Template)

Tags: audio, ads, vast

I am looking for real world examples of DAAST tags being trafficked. Anyone know of any audio players that have adopted the new standard yet?

I'm looking at Pandora, iHeartRadio and I'm still seeing VAST tags for advertisements (4-22-2015).

http://www.iab.net/DAAST

I know it's not a great question, but please if any information let me know it's appreciated.

EDIT: Doesn't look like anyone is using DAAST yet will keep this updated. Tried: Pandora, Tunein, iheartRadio, triton, spotify, radio.com, rdio. Triton on their website says they are DAAST compliant, but no DAAST observed there.

Comment: As far as I know, Triton Digital is using DAAST. But I think that the most of DSPs are using VAST, because is is somehow mature in compare to DAAST and they have started using it much more earlier. The only tricky thing there is that eash "player" will use it in a bit different way, which causes difficulties in integration. Furthermore, DAAST and VAST has a lot of things in common. I assume that in a half year most of the audio providers will use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this it is extremely new format.
[Date of publication](http://www.iabuk.net/resources/standards-and-guidelines/iab-us-digital-audio-ad-serving-template-daast) of official article is 22.01.2015

I can't found any implementation in real web-players in this time :(

Comment: This should be comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 0):

Triton Digital did support DAAST day 1... players need to specifically request this format as the default is VAST (and remained as such for backwards compatibility). Most of the advantages of DAAST are leveraged in server-to-server interfaces.